# Future Investments in Bull Market

Tags: united-states, investing

**Where should a conservative investor put his money** when:

- the market is running up so fast,
- unemployment is increasing above 6 %,
- small businesses are closing at an increased rate,
- debt is and will increase with this new administration, and
- U.S. productivity is decreasing at a higher rate.

My fears are higher inflation, interest rates will increase due to increased borrowing and there will be a major correction to the stock market some time in the near future.

Comment: I agree the future looks bleak. Take a look at any 20 year segment of the SP500 though. Even investing at the worst possible times will have you sitting net positive as long as you buy and hold. At least equities will inflate along with everything else wheras cash will just sit in a bank account and hemmorage value.

Answer (score 1):

For "truly big" questions such as this, you have to formulate an opinion on issues such as:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_decline

You predict:

> there will be a major correction to the stock market some time in the near future

If one really thinks that,

1. You could go long, but, keep tight stops (not a perfect strategy, but it will "probably stop catastrophic loss"
2. Depending on what you mean by "near" future ...... short it.

However,

3. Many people would say, on a ***long*** time scale (i.e. a lifetime of investing), there will be plenty of pullbacks, even severe ones.  "So what", that's the very point that "in the long term it goes up".

Hence,

- say the basis is 100 today
- it runs up to 200
- as you wisely and correctly predict, there's a disastrous pullback to 70
- then in merely 10 or 20 years, it is up to 500 or 1000

If those four things happen, what's the best thing anyone can do? Indeed, buy today at 100 and forget about it.  If you try and guess where the "dip to 70" is, you'll miss it all.

(I don't advocate or anti-advocate that view, I'm just outlining it. Thus, if you believe in "American Decline" {perhaps blame wikipedia?!} you would think that view is stupid.  ie, in the next 30 years America will become as crap as other failed empires ... British, Russian, Roman etc. In that view, it would be throwing your money away to put you "100" in today.)

Comment: Have a look at the European or Japanese stock market. It is not guaranteed to go up in the long term.

Comment: Indeed, that's what my answer says.  the Japanese market is a great example !

Comment: Also the best thing you could do in your situation is to not buy until it goes down to 70. Of course in reality you don't know that until it happens, but we're supposing that you do.

Answer (score 0):

> debt is and will increase with this new administration

Faster than during the *current* administration?

> My fears are ... there will be a major **correction** to the stock market some time in the near future.

1. You can't lose money in CDs, TIPS and Treasury Bills.
2. The market recovers from **corrections** relatively quickly (where "relatively" is relative).

Thus, the question is: how conservative are you?

**My** money is about 50/50 bond/equity funds consisting of:

- the least junky junk bonds - intermediate length,
- dividend stocks (on the presumption that they're high quality companies),
- consumer staples (you're always going to need toilet paper),
- municipal bonds - intermediate length, and
- the S&P 500 (due to the limitations of my 401k).

The goal is *asset protection* (won't fall as far during a correction) with *growth potential* (but won't grow as fast during a bull market) as I stare at retirement.  Of course, I well understand that my strategy might utterly and completely fail, especially if the economy really tanks, and I accept that risk.